# Count all invoices that occurred in a specific month and year in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, aggregate

I have a date of the current invoice I am inputting, Proforma_Invoice_Date

```
Dim giveMonth AS Integer
Dim giveYear As iNTEGER
Dim vLast As Variant

giveMonth = Month(Proforma_Invoice_Date)
giveYear = Year(Proforma_Invoice_Date)

vLast = DCount("Order_No", "Proforma Invoice Form Table", If give month = Month(previous ) and give year = Year (previous inputs))
```

Can someone help me how to code this, please?

Comment: Why use VBA? DCount() expression could be in textbox ControlSource.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Proforma_Invoice_Date is name of both field in `Proforma Invoice Form Table` and control on form consider:

```
Dim giveMonth AS Integer
Dim giveYear As Integer
Dim vLast As Variant

giveMonth = Month(Me.Proforma_Invoice_Date)
giveYear = Year(Me.Proforma_Invoice_Date)

vLast = DCount("*", "Proforma Invoice Form Table", _
               "Month(Proforma_Invoice_Date) = " & giveMonth & _
               " AND Year(Proforma_Invoice_Date) = " & giveYear)
```

Or just:

```
Dim vLast As Integer
vLast = DCount("*", "Proforma Invoice Form Table", _
               "Format(Proforma_Invoice_Date, 'yyyymm')=" & _
               Format(Me.Proforma_Invoice_Date, "yyyymm"))
```

Strongly advise not to use spaces in naming convention. A better table name would be `tblProformaInvoices`.

Comment: It is counting 1 every time, enven if the date is the same. Does Month(Proforma_Invoice_Date) reference all dates in the table? aka all entries?

Comment: It will count all records that match the date criteria. So if 2 records match that date then the count is 2. If this is not what you want, then edit question to show sample data and desired result as formatted tables.